# Speeding up very long connection times to PostGIS DB caused by complex views

Tags: qgis, postgis, performance

When connecting to a PostGIS database to add a postgis layer, all table and views are scanned by QGIS in order to define the geometry type (if I understand well the query performed). 
My problem is that I have complex views, quite long to be queried, that are not meant to be queried without a restricting WHERE clause. The automatic Qgis queries thus take more than half an hour to perform, and the application is frozen in the mean time.

Is there a way to tell Qgis to drop the query if no answer was obtained before a timeout, and to assume the geometry type is unknown for these layers ?

Comment: Try specifying the view's geometry type in geometry_columns table. (Just enter the line manually.) As far as I remember, that should help.

Comment: What versions of QGIS/PostGIS?

Comment: Thank you underdark ! Adding lines in geometry_columns does the trick.